# During PushSegue in IOS destination controller views are appearing in source viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am facing an strange issue, very strange to me, I have a ViewController 1 and ViewController 2 , ViewController2 has many subviews, appropriate subview will be displayed during ViewDidLoad, I recently changed other parts of app, but suddenly am facing a issue during segue from viewcontroller 1 (VC1) to viewcontroller 2(VC2), following is the issue

During Push Segue From VC1 to VC2, on VC2 viewdidload, I move a subview x position to -320 and another subview x position to 0, to get left-to-right animation of subviews, what happened was during animation, VC2's subview are appearing in VC1 , because this is am facing flash in VC2, same thing happening during popViewController animation too.

I checked all the code, I didn't find anything strange!

To summarize, issues are,

1. during push segue Viewcontroller 2 subviews are appearing in viewcontroller 1 (partly)
2. during pop viewcontroller also same things are happening

Code looks like below,

On VC1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
ViewController2 *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
        [view setIS_EDIT_REQ:YES];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

On VC2 ViewDidLoad,

```
[fromView setFrame:CGRectMake(-self.view.bounds.size.width, fromView.frame.origin.y, fromView.frame.size.width,fromView.frame.size.height)];
[toView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, toView.frame.origin.y, toView.frame.size.width, toView.frame.size.height)];
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: i edited by adding relevant code, its simple push segue , i checked, only on push segue the issue is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clipping the self.view in viewDidLoad in your VC2:-

```
self.view.clipsToBounds = YES.
```

Comment: YES, man thanks! it works!!!, i get it now, but the strange thing is other ViewController works fine with same view pattern without this clipping to bounds. anyhow thank you!